# How can I restore a deleted username using its old home folder?

Tags: 11.10, home-directory, re-installation, users

I recently upgraded my ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10, but while playing around trying to restore the GNOME classic (I really don't like the unity), I screwed something up. Ubuntu did not came back after restarting... I was stuck.

So I burned an installation CD and reinstalled Ubuntu (upgrade from 11.10 to 11.10) so the data was saved. However, I used a different username on installation by mistake, and now I've got two home folders: `/home/new_user/` and `/home/old_user/`.

The old_user is not registered as a user (it's not listed in the LightDM login screen), and I really just need one user, with my old data and configuration.

So: is there a quick way to fix it? As in, get my old_user to be the only user with all my settings back?

Thank you.

Comment: Just copy the contents of the home folder to the new one, including the hidden folders, and there is no "classic" session anymore Unity uses Gnome 3 not Gnome 2 as before so, either you completly uninstall gnome 3 and install gnome 2 or use another enviroment.

Comment: just copying won't be sufficient...
i had some modifications to /opt & /etc folders as well...
(I installed some stuff there...)
also, what about all the environment variables?
or anything else i might have changed and forgot about...?

Comment: Copying will probably be your best bet.  As far as /opt, and /etc,  unless you know what you're doing, you'll be better off just reinstalling whatever you had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option would be indeed to turn the new user into the old user.

Have a look at the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
new_user:x:1000:1000:New User,,,:/home/new_user:/bin/bash
```

Edit this line only as root to:

```
old_user:x:1000:1000:Old User,,,:/home/old_user:/bin/bash
```

Then reset the old users password: `passwd old_user` as root.

Comment: eventually i reinstalled again using the correct name, and deleted the unneeded folder. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of the home directory of a user - perhaps that's what you want. Read about the `usermod` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your /home/new_user and only want data like your favorites of your firefox and the configuration (for example) move it..

```
sudo mv /home/old_user/.mozilla /home/new_user
```

move every configuration file from the old to the new one.

other solucion if you have the /home in other partition change your fstab settings..