# Can't boot into Ubuntu; kernel panic-not syncing

Tags: grub2

I have both Ubuntu and Win 10 installed, I'm currently using Win 10.

When I was running Ubuntu, I got an update pop-up, I downloaded all the updates and started the installation, but it got stuck at configuring grub-pc (grey screen), so I just ignored it, and continued using Ubuntu normally. Now, when I try to launch Ubuntu, I get this error:

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on 
unknown block(0,0)
```

I assume the update broke grub, how do I fix this?

Comment: Please refer to this('http://askubuntu.com/questions/123960/kernel-panic-on-booting?rq=1'). Try re-installing.

Comment: That doesn't look very close to my problem, both of Win 10 and Ubuntu were working fine until I downloaded an update.